# Splitting .avi files in Java

Tags: java, movie

I have .avi video files that are somewhat large (one or two are in upwards of 13 gigabytes). I have a csv file with starting times and ending times like so:

```
start        end
00:00:23     00:03:24
etc          etc
```

I would like to split this .avi file into smaller video files (.avi preferrably, but not required) based on the `start` and `end` positions specified in the csv file.

My question is: how can I do this in Java? Note that reading in the csv file is not the problem, but rather, how can I write code to grab a clip out of a video file?

Note: If Java is **really** not suitable for a task like this, can C++ do it? And if so, what would the code look like that in that case? And if C++ can't do it, what can? Or maybe I can use command line tools? I'm on Mac OS X.

Comment: how is the AVI file encoded?

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry...

Comment: I haven't tried anything...I tried a search, but didn't find much.

Comment: I'm sure they are command line tools that you can use in Linux. I'm not entirely sure if Java is best for this, though.

Comment: I'm on Mac...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Call an external program to do the splitting. [Mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) can do this:

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -forceidx -idx -o out.avi [filename] -ss [startTime] -endpos [duration]
```

Comment: I downloaded Mplayer and ran ./configure and now it began to download but then it said "Error: yasm not found"